# android app installed but not able to see

Tags: android

I am new to android app development. I created an app using Eclipse 
        and successfully   installed on my device. Even it got installed on 
        the emulator.But, I can't see it!
        I have tried everything like adding :

1. In `manifest.xml`

   ```
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. Re-installing
3. Tried directly sending and installing .apk to the device 
          (not only by running on eclipse)
4. Restarting my eclipse

and so on.

Let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: can you please provide full manifest code?

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to be on the main page. Go to downloaded applications on your device and check if its there. Also make sure USB debugging in turned on in the developers options on your phone. Also read [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the list of installed packages?

```
$ adb shell pm list packages | grep your.package.name
```

Or just look up the directory.

```
$ adb shell ls /data/app
```

If it's really installed but not be shown in the launcher, then it would be a manifest code issue, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem few month ago, then i got that i am using more category and action tag in activity.

like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.login.UserLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="t4jsample"
                android:scheme="oauth" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

but my problem solved using this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.login.UserLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="t4jsample"
                android:scheme="oauth" />

        </intent-filter>
```

So i want to say that please check your code and let me know that you are getting some this case in your code.